# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'LanguageClient' not found

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

just using playing around with Google's Natural Language API with php, but I can't seem to run a simple example.

Here is the basic for my php:

```
<?php

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Language\LanguageClient;

# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = '<My Project Name>';

# Instantiates a client
$language = new LanguageClient([
'projectId' => $projectId
]);

# The text to analyze
$text = 'Hello, world!';

# Detects the sentiment of the text
$annotation = $language->analyzeSentiment($text);
$sentiment = $annotation->sentiment();

echo 'Text: ' . $text . 'Sentiment: ' . $sentiment['score'] . ', ' . $sentiment['magnitude'];
```

?>

But it comes up with this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'LanguageClient' not found in /User/zan/Zan/classifier/test.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/zan/Zan/classifier/test.php on line 11
```

I used composer to install google/cloud, but have no clue why it's unable to find LanguageClient. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: should your project id be public?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the composer autoloader?

```
include __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
```

This example assumes you ran composer install in the same directory your code is running. Modify the path accordingly to match your configuration.

Comment: Hey jdp, I just included it as it was missing from my original file. The error still persists though.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick update, so I managed to get it working in the end. Since it was a new laptop, most of my php files weren't setup correctly.

I was missing these components:

```
autoconf
pecl
php-unit
grpc
protobuf
pcre
```

Lastly, running a

```
composer update
```

within the directory and adding the header

```
include __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
```

I then ran the script and it worked, thanks to jdp for add and Martin for the heads up.